# How to get the content from webview and display it in a Textview

Tags: android, webview

In my app, I need to display the content of a `webview` to the user via `textView` so that they can make changes for further use.

Can this be possible by reading the screen of the phone and displaying in a `textView`?
Or is there any function in `webview` which only retrieves the text shown in the URL to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Also take help from here: https://developer.android.com

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29

Get text content from a webview

**Here is the code** 
 **strong text**

```
 package test.android.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WebviewTest2Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        TextView contentView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contentView);

        /* An instance of this class will be registered as a JavaScript interface */ 
        class MyJavaScriptInterface 
        { 
            private TextView contentView;

            public MyJavaScriptInterface(TextView aContentView)
            {
                contentView = aContentView;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unused") 

            public void processContent(String aContent) 
            { 
                final String content = aContent;
                contentView.post(new Runnable() 
                {    
                    public void run() 
                    {          
                        contentView.setText(content);        
                    }     
                });
            } 
        } 

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(contentView), "INTERFACE"); 
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
            @Override 
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
            { 
                view.loadUrl("javascript:window.INTERFACE.processContent(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText);"); 
            } 
        }); 

        webView.loadUrl("http://MIH.blogspot.com");
    }
}
```

**file.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contentView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nothing is getting displayed in the text view with this code. I need the script to be working for mobile response website too.

Comment: Is there a way to use AccessibilityEvent for this scenario ?